# Is this refraction issue a bug? I can't fix it

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

I have made a glass tumbler with very simple glass shader and absorption. I want to add a bump but if I duplicate the material for the bump faces, I get weird black backfaces in the render, even before I modify it?. If I assign the exact material with same name, it doesn't happen. Copy same material with a new name gives me the problem. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? Any idea of a work-around?

Blender 4.0 Cycles. 4090 GPU.

File:  [image]

Thanks.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I've added it above. Thanks

Comment: i think this is due to the density : the selected ring has no volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When same name (in fact, same material), all faces have same material and all is calculated as if one material for the entire mesh.

If you create a copy, and assign it to some faces, these faces won't have any volume, as they are in the screen captures you provided.

So, for a same density, the result won't be the same: the "volume absorption" node won't give the same result.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. I did try and make the faces on the inside of the 'ring' selection the same dupe material but that didn't work either... So, any idea how to make this work? I need to add bump logo embosses to glass bottles for a client and in my other software back in the day (Cinema with Corona) I just added a bump to the selection area and it worked perfectly Probably because glass density wasn't calculated using volume node. How on earth would you do this in cycles? I can't apply bump to the whole bottle as the map would have to be huge and it would be a major pain to UV it. Hmmm.

Comment: can something like this be a solution? https://i.stack.imgur.com/or17D.png

Comment: Yes! That is the way to go. While trying to sleep I was thinking perhaps a named UV map for different bump maps, but geometry ID would work too. I"ll have a play today.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used two UV maps. Worked perfectly. Cheers

[image]